# Memory-efficient representation of dates in php

Tags: php, memory-efficient

I am computing a large list of date pairs (start and end) and am running into memory issues.
My current representation is string based and still inefficient:

Currently I serialize the two dates as `manual-YYYY-MM-DD-YYYY-MM-DD` which is 28 bytes.
I could get this down to 16 by switching to `YYYYMMDDYYYYMMDD`.

However if I am changing the format now, I was wondering if there's an even more efficient solution. In theory there are not too many dates, so a 4 byte int should suffice, bringing me down to 8 byte.

I initially decided for a string representation because it's (a) human readable and (b) easily deduplicatable (think of an array of such periods and `in_array`)

To give an idea of the numbers: I am setting  up an array of period arrays, so a list of 813.000 arrays that contains altogether 65 million such items (many many duplicates, most of the time it's month start-to-end like 2021-05-01-2021-05-31). So I am also interested if some lookup dictionary soluotion might help...

Comment: Do you have only "date" values or is there a "time" component as well?

Comment: I feel like you're trying to optimize in the wrong place (low-level). Is there anything about your application that you could redesign so you don't have to process such large quantities of data at once? Any way to process this in chunks? What do you need 65 million dates at once for?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what "easily deduplicatable" means exactly but I'd say that storing dates as strings is the worst possible format to accomplish duplicates handling because slight variations (`2021-05-01`, `2021-5-01` ) can easily slip if you aren't careful.

Comment: I guess not, @El_Vanja, I manage a large directed acyclic graph and my task is to find one bottom-up serialization of it. So at one stage, I have to have all this "in one hand". Any divide-an-conquer strategy would need duplicate graph data such that I would run into other memory issues there.

Comment: Please share more details about your problem such that others could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save memory, you could store a date as an `int` representing the number of days since a reference date, such as the earliest date, if you know what that is in advance, or maybe a date definitely earlier than the entire data set otherwise.

An `int` occupies the size of a `zend_value`, 8 bytes in PHP >= 7, since it's stored directly as part of the `zend_value` itself (see [`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L286), which is part of [`_zval_struct`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L306), aka [`zval`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L90)) and thus has no memory overhead at all.

It's the lowest possible memory footprint a value can have, since anything other than an `int` (`lval` in [`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L287), a [`zend_long`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_long.h)) or `double` (`dval` in [`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L288), a `double`) is stored as a pointer to a value allocated separately (`*str`, `*arr`, `*obj`, etc... in [`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L290)), which takes up both the size of the pointer, which is equal to the size of the `zend_value`, and the size of the structure it's pointing to.

For example, a string ([`zend_string`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L344)) takes: 8 bytes (the size of [`zend_refcounted_h`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L333) for `gc`) + 8 bytes (the size of [`zend_ulong`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_long.h#L32) for `h`) + 8 bytes (the size of `size_t` for `len`) + 1 byte (the size of `char` for `val`) = 25 bytes of overhead + 8 bytes (the size of the `zend_value`) = 33 bytes for an empty string + one more byte for each character (or multiple for multibyte strings).

You could fit 4 `int`s in the memory occupied by an empty string.

If you want to calculate exactly how much memory a PHP value takes, keep in mind that you need to account for the overhead added by the [`zval`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L306) containing the [`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_types.h#L307), which can vary depending on PHP version.

Since you have date ranges, you could also consider representing a range as an `int` (something like `$first_day * 1000000 + $last_day`), thus saving the overhead of having two `zval`s to represent two `int`s.

---

A lookup table should help too, especially if you have a lot of similar dates.

You could setup an array of dates and an index array. When you encounter a date, see if index[date] exists and, if so, then the value is the index in the date array, if not, then insert it in the date array and store the index. Something like:

```
if (!isset($index[$date])) {
    $dates []= $date;
    $index[$date] = count($dates) - 1;
}
$date_index = $index[$date];
```

Now you can store `$date_index`es instead of the full dates, and can reference `$index` to retrieve dates when needed.

---

The dates don't have to be human readable in memory, just when you display them.

So you can write a display function that does all that's necessary to display the data in human readable form: obtain the date from `$dates` using `$date_index`, then convert it from its internal representation to a readable string.

---

I also encourage you to consider [El_Vanja's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658158/memory-efficient-representation-of-dates-in-php/67658297#comment119588524_67658158). This sounds like a long running task, not something the user needs to see as a response to a request, so maybe you could process the data in smaller batches instead of processing it all at once.

If the input doesn't change, and therefore the result of the computation doesn't change either, then also consider caching the result so you don't have to do all of this again. In this situation, you could also consider doing the computation and caching the result as soon as a number of data entries become available, which should use a lot less processing power and have results available sooner as well.

Comment: Am I missing something, but I thought one integer is 8 byte on a 64 bit system? @rid

Comment: @olidem, you're right, the integer is stored directly inside a `zend_value` and it occupies the size of the `zend_value`, which is 8 bytes in PHP 7. You can think of it as not having any memory overhead at all, since this is the lowest possible memory a PHP value can take, as they are all represented by `zend_value`s.  Added explanation.